# My husband making me orgasm with his hands: is this counted as masturbation?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, husband-wife, masturbation

When me and my husband are having sex he fingers me and rubs my vagina so I have orgasm so I wanted to know that is this the same as masturbation and is it haram to do this. I feel this is haram because I release something from my body which comes out from the use of hands.

Answer (score 4):

It's considered a form of "masturbation" in the English language ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/masturbation)), but this is irrelevant to its permissibility.

Spousal (mutual) masturbation is considered permissible by scholars (even strict ones).

> It is permissible for the couple to stimulate each other's private parts as a form of enhancing sexual gratification.
> <sub>[AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/6229.html) (also [AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/10366.html))</sub>
>
> It is permitted to a husband and wife to masturbate each other.
> <sub>[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83147)</sub>
>
> It is not haraam, rather, it is permissible, because it is a part of the enjoyment which Allaah has allowed.
> <sub>[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/826)</sub>
>
> Q 784: Is it permissible for a husband to masturbate using his wife’s hand?
> A: It is not an instance of ḥarām masturbation.
> <sub>[leader.ir](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjI0bqQw9DZAhUKXBQKHSbMCbsQFggtMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.leader.ir%2Fen%2Fbook%2F23%2Fpdf%2Fdownload&usg=AOvVaw06-EvsNxS-15N2AVXnr_si)</sub>

However, AskImam considered a husband masturbating his wife during menses as haram:

> It is Haraam (strictly prohibited) for the husband to masturbate his wife while she is menstruating.
> <sub>[AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/11198.html)</sub>